# Speakers ON & Off issue while Handling Calls programmatically in android

Tags: android, telephonymanager, speaker

I am working on an application that is handling incoming and outgoing calls. I am able to handle Incoming and outgoing calls Successfully using **Telephony manager**.

The issue what i am facing here is Turn Speaker Phone on and off is not working properly only for Samsung S3 and Nexus Devices(Speakers is turning on with Noise). It is working good in **Samsung Duos** and **Micromax**.

Please tell me is there any additional code i need to use to make it work.

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);    


if (audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn()) {
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
} else {
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
}
```

Comment: how u solve it.I am also facing this problem

Comment: Any solution ??? M getting same issue with samsung 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Do not change mode of audioManager.

i.e. remove line :-
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

If you change mode of audio manager then you need to restore it to previous mode also after ending a call.